# Command stops the bash script before it finishes

Tags: bash, shell, adb

I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
uninstall ()
{
  echo "$device : uninstalling the app..."
  adb -s $device uninstall "fr.inria.es.electrosmart.debug"
}
install_app ()
{
  echo "$device : installing the app..."
  adb -s $device install -r /run/netsop/u/sop-nas2a/vol/home_diana/nagarwal/StudioProjects/es-android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
}
install_tests ()
{
  echo "$device : installing the tests..."
  adb -s $device install -r /run/netsop/u/sop-nas2a/vol/home_diana/nagarwal/StudioProjects/es-android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest.apk
}
run_tests ()
{
  echo "$device : running the tests..."
  adb -s $device shell "am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class fr.inria.es.electrosmart.activities.TestAgreement fr.inria.es.electrosmart.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" || true
}

adb devices | while read line
do
    if [ ! "$line" = "" ] && [ `echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` = "device" ]
    then
        device=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo "$device $@ ..."
        uninstall
        install_app
        install_tests
        run_tests
    fi
done
```

It's supposed to run the tests on all the connected devices. I have two devices connected to my computer. But the test only runs on the first device and the script stops before running on the second device.

I think that the command `adb -s $device shell "am instrument -w -r -e debug false -e class fr.inria.es.electrosmart.activities.TestAgreement fr.inria.es.electrosmart.debug.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" || true` is responsible for crashing the script.

Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Does `adb` read from stdin?  If so, it is consuming the data intended to be read by your while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `abd` is reading from stdin,  it is consuming the data intended to be read by your while loop.  To avoid this, try closing stdin for the body of the loop so nothing can eat the data:

```
adb devices | while read device label _; do
    if test "$label" = device; then
        echo "$device $@ ..."
        uninstall
        install_app
        install_tests
        run_tests
    fi <&-
done
```

Another common idiom is to `read` from a different file descriptor, or to redirect input from `/dev/null` or `/dev/tty` rather than closing the input.  And, if you are on a system that doesn't have `/dev/tty` but want to have the inner loop read from the original script's stdin, you can do:

```
exec 3<&0
adb devices | while read device label _; do
   ...
   fi <&3
done
```

Of course, this requires that your script use a currently unused file descriptor for the dup, and hence is a bit fragile.

Comment: It works... but can you please explain a bit more how it is working or  links to some good resources where i can find it.

Comment: The trouble is that `adb` is reading from its stdin, and in your code adb's stdin is the same pipe that the `while` loop is reading from.  So the while loop reads one line of input, and then `adb` reads all the rest.  The next time `read` tries to read something, there's nothing left so it returns non-zero and the while loop does not enter a 2nd iteration.  The solution is to make `adb` not read from the same pipe as the while loop.

Comment: the easiest solution in this particular case (of short running `adb devices` command) is to redesign the code so the outer loop would consume the whole command output at once and then iterate over it - basically replacing `command | while read var; do` with `for var in $(command); do`